# How to bind RGB color to RDLC report?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, rdlc, rgb

this is my scenario: I'm developing one WPF application with .NET Framework 4 and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

I have one RDLC report with a data table and the report's data source is one custom object. At runtime I send to my report a list of my custom object.

My goal is color each cell of my table with a value defined inside my custom object but my color cannot be a text value (white, red ecc.), it must be a RGB value (127 255 212, 229 43 80 ecc).

```
+----------+----------+------------+
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3   |
+----------+----------+------------+
| Red      | Green    | Trasparent |
+----------+----------+------------+
| Green    | Yellow   | Purple     |
+----------+----------+------------+
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this: [Binding R G B properties of color in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978316/binding-r-g-b-properties-of-color-in-wpf)

Otherwise, you can bind to an integer with this value:

```
int RGB = (Red << 16) | (Green << 8) | Blue;
```

Where `Red`, `Green`, and `Blue` are each 0-255

Or hold a `Color` struct created like this: `Color.FromRgb(Red, Green, Blue)`

Answer (score 0):

the solution of this problem is that: you can bind the color with a string with this format: #HEXCOLOR.

I use this piece of code for retrieve my string:

```
private static string ToHex(int value)
{
   return String.Format("#{0:X}", value);
}
```

Bye