# How do I bind ARGB values to a rectangle fill property in a combo box item?

Tags: wpf

I have a combobox of custom objects each of which is displayed as a colored rectangle and beside it a text.

I have the ARGB values I want to display from the object, but I want to convert that to a color and set it to the fill property of the rectangle.  So far I have the following based on this post 
[Binding R G B properties of color in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1978316/1462656)

How do you specify which propertied in SubCategory to pass to the value converter? And how to set the result of the converter to the Fill property of the rectangle?

//XAML

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <local:ArgbConverter x:Key="argbConverter"></local:ArgbConverter>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubCategories}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSubCategory, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEditable="False" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="SubCategory_ComboBox_TextChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="Aqua"  Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2" ></Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

//Value Converter

```
public class ArgbConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var a = System.Convert.ToByte(values[0]);
        var r = System.Convert.ToByte(values[1]);
        var g = System.Convert.ToByte(values[2]);
        var b = System.Convert.ToByte(values[3]);

        return new Color() { A = a, B = b, R = r, G = g };
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

//VIEWMODEL

```
public ObservableCollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SubCategory>() { new SubCategory() { name = "person" } };
```

//SubCategory class

```
public class SubCategory
{
    //default values - each of these objects will have different argb values
    public int A { get; set; } = 95;
    public int R { get; set; } = 225;
    public int G { get; set; } = 80;
    public int B { get; set; } = 25;

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use `IValueConverter` instead of `IMultiValueConverter`?

**XAML**

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource argbConverter}}" 
           Width="16" Height="16"/>
```

**Converter**

```
public class ArgbConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var item = value as SubCategory;
        var a = System.Convert.ToByte(item.A);
        var r = System.Convert.ToByte(item.R);
        var g = System.Convert.ToByte(item.G);
        var b = System.Convert.ToByte(item.B);

        return new SolidColorBrush(new Color() { A = a, B = b, R = r, G = g });
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already implemented an IMultiValueConverter. So the obvious answer seems to be a `MultiBinding`, with four Bindings to the A, R, G and B properties:

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource argbConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="A"/>
                    <Binding Path="R"/>
                    <Binding Path="G"/>
                    <Binding Path="B"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </SolidColorBrush.Color>
        </SolidColorBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```